# Using Lagrangian multipliers to check the solution

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

suppose we have an objective function $f(x)$ that we want to maximize subject to constraint $g(x)=c$.

What I do next is set up Lagrangian optimization as follows and take the derivative

\begin{align*}
L(x)&=f(x)+\lambda (g(x)-c)\\
\frac{dL(x)}{dx}&=f'(x)+\lambda g'(x)
\end{align*}

So, we have to solve 
\begin{align*}
f'(x)+\lambda g'(x)=0
\end{align*} in order to find a critical point. ( Up to here this  was a usual procedure)

In my case the problem is that equation $f'(x)+\lambda g'(x)=0$ is way to complicated to solve. However, the good thing is that I have a candidate for the solution, call it $x^*$.

So since Lagrangian equation is sufficient and necessary for existence of critical point, I simply plugged in $x^*$

\begin{align*}
f'(x^*)+\lambda g'(x^*)=0
\end{align*}
and found required $\lambda$.

My question: is there a way to check whether $x^*$ is minimum or a maximum from what I did?

Comment: As I recall, it can still be a saddle point, so no, this will not work.

Comment: Could  you point me to a reference or an example where one of the solution to Lagrangian optimization is a saddle point? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that $g'(x^*)$ fulfills a regularity condition (for instance: $g'(x^*)$ has full rank). Then you need to check second-order derivatives:

If the Hessian of the Lagrangian at $(x^*,\lambda)$ is positive (or negative) definite then $x^*$ is a local minimum (or maximum).

If the Hessian is not positive (or negative) semi-definite then $x^*$ is not a local minimum (or maximum).

Comment: Thank you. So there is a possibility that my solution is a saddle point?

Comment: Also, must Lagrangian multipliers be positive for maximum to occur? Or they can be what ever.

Comment: The Lagrange multipliers to equality constraint do not carry any information in their sign. Hence, no.

Comment: Sorry, I am asking this many questions. This is the last one. If its a constraint of the type $g(x) \le c$ and I set up Lagrangian like this $f(x) -\lambda (g(x) - c)$, does the sign of Lagrangian multiplier have to be positive for the maximum?

Comment: Sorry. Another question. Can you recommend any text on Lagrange multipliers that show how to deal with constraints of the type $g(x)<c$? Thank you

Comment: The constraint $g(x)<c$ is open so you may not have a solution, you need to use $g(x)\le c$ instead. In the case of inequalities you want to use Karush-Kuhn-Tucker instead of Lagrange's approach.